# How do I install SDL Mobile?

Tags: 2013, context-engine

I have some questions about SDL Mobile.

Maybe you can help me getting an idea, what I have to do to activate this feature inside Tridion?

I'm installing a new server with SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 on a Windows platform with IIS.

What is my part from the installation side to provide the SDL Mobile integration?
I’m not programming the templates, normally I look for the administration part of the system (setup, installation and so on).

Is there a separate installation-package for this?

It will help me if you could describe it for me in a short documentation please. For me it is not so clear if I check this by SDL LiveContent.

Maybe this is possible from your side, hopefully...

Answer (score 9):

SDL Mobile consists of 3 parts – the API, known as the Context Engine Cartridge (CEC), the Mobile Device database, and Contextual Image Delivery (CID). The CEC is included with Tridion 2013 SP1, so it can be installed via the generic installer.

However, do beware that SDL Mobile is a separately paid for module, you must have purchased this in order to use the CEC, as SDL will need to activate IP addresses from the server accessing the Tridion Context Engine.

This is needed for obtaining the device database which is proprietary (one or more IP addresses can be whitelisted for access) and the DB will need to be synced on a regular basis, as new devices come out all the time.

Comment: As usual the current 2013 SP1 documentation does a stellar job of making this clear. It mentions the whitelist, but that there is a cost it getting on it!

Answer (score 8):

SDL Mobile is an add-on to your existing setup.  The existing setup should have the following:

- Content Manager
- Content Delivery (Deployer and CD web service)
- Content Presentation
- Ambient Data Framework
- XPM

Once you have those items installed and working, SDL Mobile addons are:

- Context Engine Cartridge for the Ambient Data Framework.  This includes a couple of Jar files and a text based Device DB
- contextual image delivery web service.

So, install the cartridge (See SDLLive - I'm not sure exactly what was unclear there for you). Don't forget to update your device DB by runnin the dos command specified in the docs.

Next, register the mobile User Controls in your web.config (details in SDLive Docs).

To verify that it works, try a simple jexl expression in your web app's aspx page.

Then install the Image Web Service.  This is the same procedure as installing odata or the Deployer. The only diff is the jars in your lib and web.xml config (again, this is clearly documented on SDLLive)

To summarize, start by installing Tridion the usual way. Once you learn how to do that, install the addon for Mobile.  For the micro details around this, do go to the SDLIve docs.  I suspect your challenge is to first understand what all the moving parts are so you know where to look in the docs, but all the details are there and are quite well documented.