# Is it necessary to use SDL mobile to use Contextual Image Delivery while using DXA 1.3 JAVA?

Tags: 2013-sp1, dxa, contextual-image-delivery, sdl-mobile

Is it necessary to use SDL mobile to use Contextual Image Delivery while using DXA 1.3 JAVA? Is there a separate license fee for using contextual image delivery ? I am currently using SDL Tridion 2013 sp1.

Comment: SDL mobile is Paid. check answers on it http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/8064/how-do-i-install-sdl-mobile

Comment: Correction, SDL Mobile was paid, but now it is included in the core suite.

Comment: with web 8 or 2013-sp1 as well, secondly is sdl mobile cost already included in package/core-suite whether to use it or not?

Comment: In Web 8 Mobile is part of CD. Upgrade and you get it. With 2013 SP1 it is a paid add-on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contextual Image Delivery is part of SDL Mobile.  But you don't have to use CID with DXA; without CID the DXA logic still provides server-side responsive images.

Comment: Thanks Rick. Is SDL mobile coming as part of SDL Tridion 2013 sp1 package ? Because earlier it was not part of SDL Tridion 2013 sp1 package.

Comment: The SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 package didn't change. SDL Mobile is included in SDL Web 8, though.